# How do I prevent my variables from losing their data each iteration(button click)?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that needs to store the user input from a field each time a button is pressed and keep a running total.

Ideally, the button_click should grab the users inputed number and add it to Integer RunningTotal to create the updated value for int RunningTotal.

It should do this every time I enter in a new integer and press the button.

E.g I enter 5, click button, RunningTotal = 5. 
I enter 5, click button, RunningTotal = 10.

The problem is it runs this code as if it were FRESH every iteration(button click) and does not store any data from the variables.

**Edit with Code by Request:**

```
Private Sub PickUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PickUp.Click

    Dim userInput As Integer = PickUpInputTextBox.Text

    Label2.Visible = False
    SetNumInputTB.Visible = False
    SetNum.Visible = False
    SetNum.Enabled = False

    Dim ComputerNum As Integer
    Dim InputNumber As Integer
    Dim ComputerSticks As Integer
    Dim PlayerSticks As Integer
    Dim RunningTotal As Integer


    InputNumber = SetNumInputTB.Text

    ComputerNum = Int((inputNumber / 2) * Rnd() + 1)
    MsgBox("The computer picked " & ComputerNum & " sticks")
    ComputerSticks = ComputerNum

    PlayerSticks = PickUpInputTextBox.Text
    RunningTotal = PlayerSticks + ComputerSticks

    MsgBox("Player Sticks:" & PlayerSticks & "Computer Sticks" & ComputerSticks & "Running Total: " & RunningTotal)

    If RunningTotal >= InputNumber Then
        determineWinner(1)
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: vb.net, added wrong tag sorry

Comment: Can you put your code here? Let's see what is wrong

Comment: @AAA I added the code, it's actualy for something a bit more complicated than my initial explenation, but I figured that was the easiest way to explain it.

It's for a game where the computer and user take turns picking an amount of sticks(Can't pick more than half of the starting stick value), last player to pick a stick loses.

Comment: see my answer below. `Running Total` has to be defined outside the `button_click` sub. If not, it will only exist within that scope and be initialised when you call the function. I gave an example, I hope you can adapt to your use.

Comment: let's know if the answer solved the issue

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `RunningTotal` is defined within your `button_click` function. Hence, any time the function is called (when the button is clicked), the variable is re-initialised. Define it outside the `button_click` sub in your main class and use it as follows:

```vb
Dim RunningTotal as Integer = 0
'.... other class code
Sub button_click()
'let us assume use input is stored in a variable called input
RunningTotal += input
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try declaring static variable, ie. static buttonclick as integer.

Comment: If you define a variable in the click event as `Static`, it will still only be visible in the click event of course. It may be that the variables need to be accessed elsewhere as well

Answer (score 0):

You're program is going to crash when the user types something that is not a valid integer into the TextBoxes.  Use Integer.TryParse() to determine if a valid integer was entered.

For example, change:

```
Dim userInput As Integer = PickUpInputTextBox.Text
```

To something like:

```
Dim userInput As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(PickUpInputTextBox.Text, userInput) Then
    If (userInput > 0) Then
        ' ... other existing code ...
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You must pick up one or more sticks!")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Inavlid Number of Sticks to Pick Up!")
End If
```